# Error establishing a database connection in wordpress or we can’t contact the database server at localhost

Tags: mysql, wordpress

My wordpress site showing error establishing database connection even after giving the correct database name, username, password and db_host.  I got this error when I load my site.

> " This either means that the username and password information in your wp-config.php file is incorrect or we can’t contact the database server at localhost. This could mean your host’s database server is down. "

Comment: maybe change the db host to `127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 1):

Login to Cpanel or FTP then edit your wp-config.php file 
enable there debug mode :

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );

define('WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true);
```

You will get the report of front end fix it if any error occurring there

```
define('DB_NAME', 'database-name');
define('DB_USER', 'database-username');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'database-password');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
```

recheck your database username, password, database name and host name

some time the **SPACE** creating problems

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your DB user has the proper privileges to connect from the localhost. If the existing DB user doesn't have the hostname field as the localhost, edit the existing user, or create a new user with the localhost as the hostname.